# z-index property for @ username mention

Tags: angular, mention

I created a text box in which when I type `@` it will give me username suggestions.

The problem that I am facing is when I type `@` and then I hit enter it will entres the selected username.
and then if you hit enter 5 times then the list of the username is not coming just after the `@`.

it is coming very down the place where I typed `@`

I think there is some mistake in z-index. I created a stack blitz link you can check here [Stalk Blitz code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyotig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

it is working fine on stalk blitz but it is not working correctly on my local system and I don't what is happening.

Screenshot of my local system image you can that the username suggestion list is not coming at the correct place also if I type enter 10 times then I need to scroll too much to see the list names.

can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Please update your StackBlitz link with the correct code.

Comment: @nash11 check now ..